# bootstrap - слайдер

Tags: html, bootstrap

Ребята, решил сделать в макете bootstrap - слайдер, немогу даже придумать как его засунуть. Сетка 12 колончатая, если я делаю картинку как 2 колонки - то встает 6 элементов, а места под крутилки влево-вправо - уже НЕТ. То же самое происходит если делать картинку как 3 элемента - будет уже 4 фото, а места нет. Вот как подобрать клетки для слайдера таким образом что бы по бокам было по 1 клетке для крутилок ? заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

эмм.. я так понимая, что видимо речь идет про `carousel`, даже если нет, то принцип тот же. Скажите, кто вас заставляет выравнивать его ширину по колонкам bootstrap? Почему просто не сделать еще один див внутри колонки и дать ему просто нормальный стиль?

```
<style>
    .carousel { widh: 200px; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">1 колонка</div>
        <div class="span6>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">код элементов слайдера</div>
        </div> ...
```

итого получается что слайдер и внутри колонки и занимает меньше места

Comment: да, вы правы, но эффект же не тот, как от 960 gs - там было попроще с блками, каждый стоял на своем месте.